# How to detect a pressed button using setInterval and without any event in javascript?

Tags: button, events, setinterval, detect, pressed

I want to get a pressed mouse or keyboard button from global object window or document when it's listening in setInterval.

```
setInterval(function () {

    window.mouse.button. ...;
    window.keyboard.button. ...;

    // or maybe

    document.mouse.button. ...;
    document.keyboard.button. ...;

}, 1);
```

It would be kind of my own self-made event.

**How to detect a pressed button using setInterval and without any event in javascript?**

```
setInterval(function () {

    window.mouse.button. ...;
    window.keyboard.button. ...;

    // or maybe

    document.mouse.button. ...;
    document.keyboard.button. ...;

}, 1);
```